# Debug the code after published a project on the server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've published my project on my VPS server (MVC 3 project). Now, is it somehow possible to debug the code during the project is being runned on the server ? The same way when it's running on the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

There might be but I believe the fact that you're trying to is a bad sign. By the time you deploy your app you should have proper logging and error handling which should allow you to track down any bugs that occur and reproduce them in your development environment.